# How to re-fetch data after doing a filter in React.js with useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, fetch-api

I got this component in React.js which make different kinds of filtering when I click a button, this is my code:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ModelsContext } from "../context/ModelsContext";

const FilterNav = () => {

    const { modelos, guardarModelo } = useContext(ModelsContext);
    
    const filterSegment = e => {

        const segment = modelos.filter(modelo => modelo.segment === e.target.name);
        
        guardarModelo(segment);

    }

   
    return (
        <nav className="filter-container"> 
            <div className="container">
                <h3 className="filter-element-title">Filtrar por</h3>
                <button type="button" className="filter-element">Todos</button>
                <button type="button" className="filter-element" name="Autos" onClick={filterSegment}>Autos</button>
                <button type="button" className="filter-element" name="Pickups y Comerciales" onClick={filterSegment}>Pickups y Comerciales</button>
                <button type="button" className="filter-element" name="SUVs y Crossovers" onClick={filterSegment}>SUVs y Crossovers</button>
            </div>
            <p className="filter-element-last">Ordenar por &#x5e;</p>
        </nav>
     );
}
 
export default FilterNav;
```

The information I get from the API with `useContext` in ModelsContext.jsx, here is what I wrote so far:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const ModelsContext = createContext();

const ModelsProvider = (props) => {

        //State de modelos
        const [modelos, guardarModelo] = useState([]);

        const consultarAPI = async () => {
        const api = await fetch("https://challenge.agenciaego.tech/models");
        const modelos = await api.json();
        guardarModelo(modelos);
        }

        //Cargar un modelo
        useEffect(() => {
            consultarAPI()
        }, []);

    return (
        <ModelsContext.Provider
            value={{
                modelos,
                guardarModelo
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </ModelsContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ModelsProvider;
```

My issue is that when I filter the API modelos through the `filterSegment` function I don't know how to re-fetch the data from the API, because when I do a new call to the `filterSegment` function it filters the filtered data. I've tried to add a boolean state, and I was thinking about adding another state with allthedata, but I really lost about implementing it, I'm still very new to React.js.

I've search through Stack Overflow and Google and I cannot get the answer, If you can give me a clue or some sort of guidance it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another state in the `ModelsContext`:

```
//State de modelos
const [modelos, guardarModelo] = useState([]);
const [allModelos, guardarAllModelo] = useState([]);

const consultarAPI = async () => {
    const api = await fetch("https://challenge.agenciaego.tech/models");
    const modelos = await api.json();
    guardarAllModelo(modelos);
    
    //uncomment if you want to have initial value for modelos state
    //guardarModelo(modelos);
}

// some codes ...

<ModelsContext.Provider
        value={{
            allModelos,
            modelos,
            guardarModelo
        }}
 >
        {props.children}
 </ModelsContext.Provider>
```

Then in the `FilterNav` component:

```
    const {allModelos, modelos, guardarModelo } = useContext(ModelsContext);
    
    const filterSegment = e => {

        const segment = allModelos.filter(modelo => modelo.segment === e.target.name);
        
        guardarModelo(segment);

    }
```

But this does not really re-fetch data from your web api. It just re-filters the first fetched data. if you want to re-fetch data from web api you can add `consultarAPI` in your context provider then call it somewhere.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks code is working

This is my Portfolio gallery code First time load all data when click category then get category data`enter code here`

```js
Thanks code is working 

This is my Portfolio gallery code First time load all data when click category then get category data`enter code here`
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react'`enter code here`;
import Thumnailport_list from './Thumnailport_list';
import Portlightbox from './Portlightbox';
import Functional from './Functional';
import $ from 'jquery';

const Portfolio = () => {

    const filterItem = async (categoryitem) => {

        const updateitmes = allModelos.filter((curElm) => {
            return curElm.categories === categoryitem
        })

        getporfolioState(updateitmes)


    }
    const [getporfolio, getporfolioState] = useState([])
    const [allModelos, guardarAllModelo] = useState([]);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".grid-wrap .grid li").unbind().click(function (e) {
            console.log(this.className);
            var newe = this.className;
            $('.' + newe).addClass('current show');
            $("#grid-gallery").addClass("slideshow-open");
        });

        $("#closeport").unbind().click(function (e) {
            $("#grid-gallery").removeClass("slideshow-open");
            $(".portfolio .grid li").removeClass('current show');
            $(".portfolio .slideshow ul > li").removeClass('current show');
        });
    });

    const portadd = () => {
        document.body.classList.add('portfolio');
        document.body.classList.add('at-top');

        document.getElementById('port').classList.add('no-transform');
        document.getElementById('port').classList.add('revealator-within');
        document.getElementById('port2').classList.add('no-transform');
        document.getElementById('port2').classList.add('revealator-within');
        document.getElementById('navbar-collapse-toggle').classList.remove('biohidemenu');
    }

    const getalldata = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch("/getdata", {
                method: 'Get',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }

            })
            const data = await res.json()
            // console.log("This is our data load")
            // console.log(data.portfolio)
            getporfolioState(data.portfolio)
            guardarAllModelo(data.portfolio)




        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            // history.push("/backoffice/login")
        }
    }





    useEffect(() => {
        getalldata()
        portadd()




    }, []);
    return (
        <>

            <section id="port" class="title-section text-left text-sm-center revealator-slideup revealator-once revealator-delay1">
                <h1 >my <span>portfolio</span></h1>
                <span class="title-bg">works</span>
            </section>
            <section id="port2" className="main-content text-center revealator-slideup revealator-once revealator-delay1">
                <div class="container">
                    <button className="btn btn-about " onClick={() => filterItem('mobileapp')}>Mobile</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button className="btn btn-about " onClick={() => filterItem('frontend')}>Frontend</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button className="btn btn-about " onClick={() => filterItem('gdesign')}>Graphics</button>
                </div>
                <div id="grid-gallery" className="container grid-gallery">
                    {/* Portfolio Grid Starts */}
                    <section className="grid-wrap">
                        <ul className="row grid">
                            {
                                getporfolio.map((getdata, index) => {


                                    return (
                                        <>
                                            <Thumnailport_list
                                                key={index}
                                                portID={getdata._id}
                                                imagetag={getdata.imguploadedFile}
                                                figuertext={getdata.projectname}

                                            />
                                        </>
                                    )


                                })
                            }

                        </ul>
                    </section>
                    {/* Portfolio Grid Ends */}
                    {/* Portfolio Details Starts */}
                    <section className="slideshow" id="sdfer">
                        <ul>
                            {/* Portfolio Item Detail Starts */}
                            {
                                getporfolio.map((getdata, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <>
                                            <Portlightbox
                                                idlight={getdata._id}
                                                imagelight={getdata.imguploadedFile}
                                                langport={getdata.language}
                                                clientport={getdata.client}
                                                projectnameport={getdata.projectname}
                                                previewport={getdata.preview}
                                            />

                                        </>
                                    )


                                })
                            }







                        </ul>
                        {/* Portfolio Navigation Starts */}
                        <nav>
                            {/*<span className="icon nav-prev prev"><img src="images/left-arrow.png" alt="previous" /></span>
                        <span className="icon nav-next next"><img src="images/right-arrow.png" alt="next" /></span>*/}
                            <span className="nav-close" id="closeport"><img src="images/close-button.png" alt="close" /> </span>
                        </nav>
                        {/* Portfolio Navigation Ends */}
                    </section>
                </div>
            </section>




        </>
    )
}

export default Portfolio;
```